# iOS Health Kit Clinical Patient Data

Tags: ios, mobile-application, healthkit

I have a third-party app that is attempting to gather clinical health records from the iOS Health App. I have successfully followed these [steps](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/samples/accessing_health_records) to gain access to apple healths 7 record types. For the requirements of this task, I also need to gain access to "Patient Data". This data can be found within the Apple Health App under accounts:

[image]

[image]

In the "FHIR Patient Data" tab:

[image]
[image]

Does the apple health kit API allow for this type of data fetch?

Comment: I googled "HealthKit FHIR" and the apple docs talk about how to extract the data from FHIR json. Is this what you are looking for: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/samples/accessing_a_user_s_clinical_records

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin I still feel that falls under the category of querying under apples 7 predefined record types (you can see each record type FHIR Source data by clicking through on the Browse tab => Health records => (one of the record types, Allergies, for example) => A specific condition => FHIR Source Data). You can tell me if I'm wrong there (which I might be) but I am looking for the Patient FHIR data source specifically.

Comment: Sorry thats not it. I don't see anyway to get that specific document, but what is it you exactly need? RayWenderlich has a sample of how to get name, age and bloodtype of the user, which seems to be similar data to whats contained in that record you have: https://www.raywenderlich.com/459-healthkit-tutorial-with-swift-getting-started

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin thanks for that link I'll dig into that. The info I'm looking for is first and last name, DOB, Sex, and the provider associated with the record I'm pulling (something like first, last name and some identifier like Practitioner/123456). It's also important that the data comes from the FHIR record and is not something the user can edit themselves, for example, I can edit my first, last name and DOB in the health profile section.

Answer (score -1):

The answer to your question is yes, the API supports retrieval of FHIR records. You will have to pull the data apart yourself after you get it. Here is some example code which will get the records;

```
func getClinicalDocuments()
{
    guard let cdaType = HKObjectType.documentType(forIdentifier: .CDA) else {
        print("unable to create CDA type.")
        return
    }
    allDocuments.removeAll(keepingCapacity: true)

    let cdaQuery = HKDocumentQuery(documentType: cdaType, predicate: nil, limit: HKObjectQueryNoLimit, sortDescriptors: nil, includeDocumentData: true)
    { (query, results, done, error) in

        if results != nil
        {
             for d in results!
            {
                self.allDocuments.append(d as! HKCDADocumentSample)
            }
        }

    }
     healthStore.execute(cdaQuery)
}
```

Comment: would you know how to translate this into objective-c? I'm using a react-native approach to this and the module I'm using is written in objective-c.

Comment: Also, will these include the Patient Record type as I had suggested before or just the record types that apple recommends?

Comment: This one will return ClinicalDocuments Data. 
CDA data is completely different from health records patient data. 
CDA data can be written and saved. But Health records patient data cannot be written and saved.